# format a zoo object with "dimnames"=List of 2

Tags: r, statistics, zoo

I am using the [eventstudies package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/eventstudies/eventstudies.pdf). I am using the `phys2eventtime(..)` to set up my data. However I am getting

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = integer(0)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

My guess is that, my data is wrongly formated. When I have a look at the example data which use the function in the sample:

```
    > es <- phys2eventtime(z=StockPriceReturns, events=SplitDates, width=10)
    > (str(StockPriceReturns))
'zoo' series from 2000-04-03 to 2013-03-28
  Data: num [1:3246, 1:30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:30] "Bajaj.Auto" "BHEL" "Bharti.Airtel" "Cipla" ...
  Index:  Date[1:3246], format: "2000-04-03" "2000-04-04" "2000-04-05" "2000-04-06" ...
NULL
```

compared to this my data looks like that:

```
> (str(zoo_Data))
'zoo' series from 2002-01-01 to 2013-08-20
  Data: num [1:3036] 183 183 186 191 191 ...
  Index:  Date[1:3036], format: "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" ...
NULL
```

This is different:

- The sample data uses sth like `- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2`

This can also be seen when looking at the raw data:

**sample data:**

```
> (head(StockPriceReturns))
           Bajaj.Auto       BHEL Bharti.Airtel     Cipla Coal.India   Dr.Reddy
2000-04-03         NA  4.9171044            NA  6.810041         NA -3.2541653
2000-04-04         NA -8.3348496            NA -3.368606         NA -8.3353739
2000-04-05         NA  0.3305788            NA  0.836825         NA  0.2616345
2000-04-06         NA -2.7605266            NA -2.466056         NA -1.8941289
2000-04-07         NA  3.2543548            NA  7.690426         NA  7.6961041
2000-04-10         NA  3.3107586            NA  6.154276         NA  6.4769648
```

**my data:**

```
> (head(zoo_Data))
2002-01-01 2002-01-02 2002-01-03 2002-01-04 2002-01-07 2002-01-08 
    182.83     182.83     186.40     190.57     191.17     193.25
```

The `df data`:

I am constructing the zoo object out of my data like that:

```
> dfToZoo <- function(df) {
    require(zoo)
    date <- as.Date(df[, 1], format = '%d.%m.%Y')
    #TODO have a look if the column are rightly named
    with(df, zoo(TotalReturns, date))
} 


csv_data <- read.csv(..., header = TRUE, sep = ";",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

totalReturns <- (as.double(gsub(",",".",csv_data$TotalReturn)))


df <- data.frame(csv_data$Date, totalReturns)
names(df) <- c("Date" ,"TotalReturns")


zoo_Data <- dfToZoo(df)
```

How to add the `attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2` to my data?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE 1**

This is the `example data code` from the libary package:

```
library(eventstudies)
library(zoo)

###########################

# Load data

(data(SplitDates))
(data(StockPriceReturns))

data <- StockPriceReturns

(head(StockPriceReturns))



es <- phys2eventtime(z=StockPriceReturns, events=SplitDates, width=10)
es.w <- window(es$z.e, start=-10, end=10)
SplitDates[1:3,]
```

**UPDATE 2**

This is how my own data is formatted:

```
> (str(s_dates))
'data.frame':   36799 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ unit: chr  "ZAE000006284" "ZAE000006284" "ZAE000006284" "ZAE000006284" ...
 $ when: Date, format: "2003-12-18" "2005-04-06" ...
NULL
> (str(zoo_Data))
'zoo' series from 2002-01-01 to 2013-08-20
  Data: num [1:3036] 183 183 186 191 191 ...
  Index:  Date[1:3036], format: "2002-01-01" "2002-01-02" "2002-01-03" "2002-01-04" ...
NULL
```

This is how the data from the event study package is formatted:

```
> (str(SplitDates))
'data.frame':   22 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ unit: chr  "BHEL" "Bharti.Airtel" "Cipla" "Coal.India" ...
 $ when: Date, format: "2011-10-03" "2009-07-24" ...
NULL
> (str(StockPriceReturns))
'zoo' series from 2000-04-03 to 2013-03-28
  Data: num [1:3246, 1:30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:30] "Bajaj.Auto" "BHEL" "Bharti.Airtel" "Cipla" ...
  Index:  Date[1:3246], format: "2000-04-03" "2000-04-04" "2000-04-05" "2000-04-06" ...
NULL
```

**UPDATE 3**

**Reproducable example**

I am initially reading the data in by different csv files. Please see my reproducable example:

## Reproducable example

```
library(eventstudies)
library(zoo)

s_dates <- 
  structure(list(unit = c("ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", 
                          "ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", "XS0430907989", "XS0430907989"
  ), when = structure(c(12404, 12879, 12879, 12880, 12930, 14411, 
                        14411), class = "Date")), .Names = c("unit", "when"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                            7L), class = "data.frame")

zoo_Data <- 
  structure(c(182.83, 182.83, 186.4, 190.57, 191.17, 193.25, 190.57
  ), index = structure(c(11688, 11689, 11690, 11691, 11694, 11695, 
                         11696), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")

es <- phys2eventtime(z=zoo_Data, events=s_dates, width=10)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = integer(0)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
> es.w <- window(es$z.e, start=-10, end=10)
  Error in window(es$z.e, start = -10, end = 10) : object 'es' not found
```

**UPDATE 4**

Ok when I try to convert my `zoo_data`:

```
> library(eventstudies)
> library(zoo)
> 
> s_dates <- dput(head(s_dates,30))
structure(list(unit = c("ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", 
"ZAE000006284", "ZAE000006284", "XS0430907989", "XS0430907989", 
"XS0302626899", "XS0302626899", "XS0302626899", "XS0302626899", 
"XS0302626899", "XS0302626899", "XS0266838746", "XS0187043079", 
"XS0187043079", "XS0187043079", "XF0000TZ7757", "XF0000AK5197", 
"XF0000AK5197", "XF0000AK5197", "XF0000AK5197", "XF0000AK5197", 
"USU02681027", "USU026281027", "USU026281027", "USU026281027", 
"USU026281027", "USU026281027", "USU026281027"), when = structure(c(12404, 
12879, 12879, 12880, 12930, 14411, 14411, 14599, 14600, 15134, 
15139, 15328, 15328, 13913, 14330, 14335, 14593, 13049, 12953, 
12954, 12954, 12954, 12955, 12934, 13537, 13537, 13537, 13648, 
13649, 13649), class = "Date")), .Names = c("unit", "when"), row.names = c(NA, 
30L), class = "data.frame")
> zoo_Data <- dput(head(zoo_Data,30))
structure(c(182.83, 182.83, 186.4, 190.57, 191.17, 193.25, 190.57, 
184.02, 181.34, 172.11, 169.73, 160.2, 175.09, 172.11, 170.92, 
176.58, 171.51, 170.92, 173.9, 168.54, 167.34, 166.75, 166.45, 
167.34, 164.37, 159.01, 158.11, 154.84, 156.63, 161.99), index = structure(c(11688, 
11689, 11690, 11691, 11694, 11695, 11696, 11697, 11698, 11701, 
11702, 11703, 11704, 11705, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 
11715, 11716, 11717, 11718, 11719, 11722, 11723, 11724, 11725, 
11726, 11729), class = "Date"), class = "zoo")
> 
> n = 20                       ## number of observation
> cn <- unique(s_dates$unit)   ## get response variable 
> 
> as.xts(zoo_Data)
> 
> names(zoo_Data) <- cn
> 
> es <- phys2eventtime(z=zoo_Data), events=s_dates, width=10)
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = integer(0)) : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
> es.w <- window(es$z.e, start=-3, end=3)
Error in window(es$z.e, start = -3, end = 3) : object 'es' not found
```

Comment: I am using the same lib at the moment and facing the same problem. Would love to hear some answers!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. In your first example there isn't splitDates and the second update it works fine.

Comment: @agstudy I added `Update 2` to to make my problem much more clearer. Please ask if anything further is unclear!

Comment: Thank's but I am afraid to say that your example still not reproducible. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @agstudy Thanks a lot for this tip. I think I created now a `Reproducable Example`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`phys2eventtime` Converts physical dates to event dates.

So Given a zoo time-series and an event date, it converts the physical date to the event date.  That means , if it finds an event date in the range of the zoo object , this date becomes zero and all other dates shift accordingly.

So giving this event date object:

```
          unit       when
1 ZAE000006284 2003-12-18
2 ZAE000006284 2005-04-06
3 ZAE000006284 2005-04-06
4 ZAE000006284 2005-04-07
5 ZAE000006284 2005-05-27
6 XS0430907989 2009-06-16
7 XS0430907989 2009-06-16
```

#### Conditions to convert ts --> event date

You physical time series dates (the zoo object) should fulfill 2 conditions:

- should have at least one column name (response variable) within **unit** values (COND1)
- the range date of this response variable should contain at least one event date ( when column).(COND2)

#### Create a physical time series that can be converted to an event date

Now I will create a times serie that fulfill this 2 conditions : a multi time series (xts object ) which index fall with the range of s_dates  and having column names within s_dates unit values.

```
n = 20                       ## number of observation
cn <- unique(s_dates$unit)   ## get response variable 
rr = range(s_dates$when)     ## get date range
## COND2
index = seq(rr[1],rr[2],length.out=n)   
mat = matrix(round(runif(n*2,min=150,max=200),2),ncol=2)
ev.dat = xts(mat,index)
## COND1
names(ev.dat) <- cn
```

Checking our time serie object:

```
head(ev.dat)
           ZAE000006284 XS0430907989
2003-12-18       183.27       152.89
2004-04-01       195.23       172.78
2004-07-16       190.18       164.92
2004-10-29       182.24       191.19
2005-02-12       151.78       195.81
2005-05-29       153.78       189.27
```

And without surprise it works fine :

```
(es <- phys2eventtime(z=ev.dat, events=s_dates, width=5))
(es.w <- window(es$z.e, start=-10, end=10))
head(es.w)
        2      3      4      5
-4 197.28 197.28 197.28 197.28
-3 158.54 158.54 158.54 158.54
-2 180.56 180.56 180.56 180.56
-1 194.41 194.41 194.41 194.41
0  157.64 157.64 157.64 157.64
1  151.06 151.06 151.06 151.06
```

#### How to test if your time series fulfill this 2 conditions:

As a bonus , I created a small function that 2 conditions for you:

```
check.phys2ev <- function(ev.dat,s_dates){
  is.sucess = lapply(s_dates$when,function(when){
    inter = findInterval(when, index(ev.dat))
    inter < nrow(ev.dat) && inter >1 
  })
  sum(unlist(is.sucess)) >0 &
    all(colnames(ev.dat) %in% s_dates$unit)
}

check.phys2ev(ev.dat,s_dates)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Wow thx for your answer! When you convert to an xts object: Why are you using only `r[1],r[2]`? Why are you constructin a matrix `mat`?

Comment: do you mean rr[1],rr[2]? because `range` creates length 2,  rr[1) is min dates and rr[2] is max dates. I create a matrix because in xts constructor , xts(x,index): x is a matrix and index a vector of dates.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Can I also create the `ev.dat` object out of my already existing zoo object which are in fact my data for the `StockPriceReturns`? Namely in fact my s_date consists of in my full dataset of `36799` values and my zoo_object consists of `3036`.

Comment: Yes I tried it. However I still get the same error. Please see my further `update`.

Comment: @user2051347 please read my answer carefully! `ev.dat <- as.xts(zoo_Data)` then you shouldname it with one of the variable `names(ev.dat) <- cn[1]` or 2... then use my test function to check the range of dates!

Comment: Thank you for your answer and all your help! I have one final question. After coding my program out I found out that it is now applicable to just use a univariat data set, cause I would process each dataset by dataset, which would take me days(by an estimate of 36000 events and around 1000 companies). So I was wondering I could just add to my xts object other zoo objects, so that the datastructure looks exactly like the `StockPriceReturns`. I would really appreciate your answer!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44570/discussion-between-agstudy-and-user2051347)

Answer (score 2):

@agstudy has already presented a very nice answer, using a multi variate time series as an example. Because you seem to have a univariate time series, I wish to add something on how to **avoid coercion to an "object with less than two dimensions"** when you create your `zoo` object. Here is one possible solution, where I add a dummy column to the time series, and select the focal column while using `drop = FALSE`.

Start with a univariate time series in a data frame. This first attempt clearly doesn't work due to the mismatch between dates in the `zoo` object and in `events` (as described by @agstudy), as well as the fact that the `zoo` object has less than two dimensions.

```
df <- data.frame(date = index(zoo_Data),
                 ZAE000006284 = coredata(zoo_Data))
df

# convert to zoo object
z1 <- zoo(x = df[ , -1], order.by = df$date)
z1

phys2eventtime(z = z, events = s_dates, width = 10)
# Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = integer(0)) : 
#   attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Add a date that is as large as max date in s_dates, just used here as a quick and dirty way to fulfil "COND2" (sensu @agstudy).

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(index(zoo_Data), max(s_dates$when)),
                 ZAE000006284 = c(coredata(zoo_Data), 200))
df

z1 <- zoo(x = df[ , -1], order.by = df$date)
z1
phys2eventtime(z = z1, events = s_dates, width = 10)
# Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = integer(0)) : 
#   attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

**Avoid coercion to vector**
Add a dummy column to the univariate time series. When the focal column is selected, use `drop = FALSE` to avoid coercion to vector. Then convert the univariate (but two-dimensional) time series to `zoo`:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(index(zoo_Data), max(s_dates$when)),
                 ZAE000006284 = c(coredata(zoo_Data), 200),
                 ZAE000006284_2 = c(coredata(zoo_Data), 200))
df

z2 <- zoo(x = df[ , "ZAE000006284", drop = FALSE], order.by = df$date)
z2
str(z2)   
....
attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2


phys2eventtime(z = z2, events = s_dates, width = 10)
# seems to work
```

Comment: +1! I think that this should be added to the function ( `drop=FALSE`)  .Maybe you or the OP you can contact the package maintainer.

Comment: @agstudy, Thanks for your feedback. I can notify the package maintainer about this question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for pointing this out and the great discussion. Being one of the authors of the package, I see where the problem is. If you look at the `phys2eventtime` function, it requires a `zoo` series with at least one column, as pointed out in the answers above. `zoo`/`data.frame` drops the last column and converts it to a vector unless `drop = FALSE` is provided to the subscript function.

As suggested by @Henrik and @agstudy, we cannot really do `drop = FALSE` inside the `phys2eventtime` function since the function does not know the series name. It relies on colnames of the object for the series names. For univariate series, if the object is a vector, then there is no way to know the series name and match it with the events object.

The only way I see now is by creating one-column `zoo` objects. Suggestions are of course welcome.

EDIT: I am submitting a small patch which throws out an error if the 'z' object is a vector:

`if (is.null(ncol(z))) { 
    stop(paste(deparse("z"), "should be a zoo series with at least one column."))
}`

The code is available here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/?root=eventstudies

Kindly also join the package discussion mailing list at: http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/eventstudies-discussion/